# Use "byte-like object" from urlopen.read with JSON?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urlopen

Just trying to test out very simple Python JSON commands, but I'm having some trouble.

```
urlopen('http://www.similarsitesearch.com/api/similar/ebay.com').read()
```

should output

```
'{"num":20,"status":"ok","r0":"http:\\/\\/www.propertyroom.com\\/","r1":"http:\\/\\/www.ubid.com\\/","r2":"http:\\/\\/www.bidcactus.com\\/","r3":"http:\\/\\/www.etsy.com\\/","r4":"http:\\/\\/us.ebid.net\\/","r5":"http:\\/\\/www.bidrivals.com\\/","r6":"http:\\/\\/www.ioffer.com\\/","r7":"http:\\/\\/www.shopgoodwill.com\\/","r8":"http:\\/\\/www.beezid.com\\/","r9":"http:\\/\\/www.webidz.com\\/","r10":"http:\\/\\/www.auctionzip.com\\/","r11":"http:\\/\\/www.overstock.com\\/","r12":"http:\\/\\/www.bidspotter.com\\/","r13":"http:\\/\\/www.paypal.com\\/","r14":"http:\\/\\/www.ha.com\\/","r15":"http:\\/\\/www.onlineauction.com\\/","r16":"http:\\/\\/bidz.com\\/","r17":"http:\\/\\/www.epier.com\\/","r18":"http:\\/\\/www.sell.com\\/","r19":"http:\\/\\/www.rasmus.com\\/"}'
```

but I get that same string, with a `b` in front:

```
b'{"num":20,"status":"ok","r0":"http:\\/\\/www.propertyroom.com\\/","r1":"http:\\/\\/www.ubid.com\\/","r2":"http:\\/\\/www.bidcactus.com\\/","r3":"http:\\/\\/www.etsy.com\\/","r4":"http:\\/\\/us.ebid.net\\/","r5":"http:\\/\\/www.bidrivals.com\\/","r6":"http:\\/\\/www.ioffer.com\\/","r7":"http:\\/\\/www.shopgoodwill.com\\/","r8":"http:\\/\\/www.beezid.com\\/","r9":"http:\\/\\/www.webidz.com\\/","r10":"http:\\/\\/www.auctionzip.com\\/","r11":"http:\\/\\/www.overstock.com\\/","r12":"http:\\/\\/www.bidspotter.com\\/","r13":"http:\\/\\/www.paypal.com\\/","r14":"http:\\/\\/www.ha.com\\/","r15":"http:\\/\\/www.onlineauction.com\\/","r16":"http:\\/\\/bidz.com\\/","r17":"http:\\/\\/www.epier.com\\/","r18":"http:\\/\\/www.sell.com\\/","r19":"http:\\/\\/www.rasmus.com\\/"}'
```

Subsequently, when I try to run

```
json.loads(urlopen('http://similarsitesearch.com/api/similar/ebay.com').read())
```

it gives me the error message:

> TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object"

which I'm assuming has something to do with the `b`?

I imported `urlopen` from `urllib.request`, and I am running Python 3.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 32):

The content from read() is of type *bytes* so you need to convert it to a string before trying to decode it into a json object.

To convert *bytes* to a string, change your code to:
`urlopen('http://similarsitesearch.com/api/similar/ebay.com').read().decode("utf-8")`

Answer (score 6):

You need to examine the charset specified in the `Content-Type` header and decode by that before passing it to `json.load*()`.

Comment: It appears to be UTF-8, there isn't any automatic decoding occurring? (Was there historically?)

Comment: There never was; `urllib.urlopen().read()` returned a bytestring in 2.x as well. It just so happened that `json` was okay with that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite understanding. Further clarification? :)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Pity that there are factual errors in that presentation. It claims Python doesn't support UTF-32, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It didn't, back when it was written.

Answer (score 6):

It worked well :

```
def myView(request):
    encoding = request.read().decode("utf-8")
    dic = json.loads(encoding)
    print(dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

urllib is returning a byte array, which I assume is the default in py3, and json is expecting a string. Try wrapping the return value in a str() call before invoking the json call

```
j = str(urlopen('http://similarsitesearch.com/api/similar/ebay.com').read())
json.loads(j)
```

Comment: Hmmmm, now its telling me that "No JSON object could be decoded."

Comment: That's because `str()` doesn't convert a `bytes` to a `str` in 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a [byte literal](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3112/).  Investigate how you get the data with http,  or how the API returns the data in the headers.