# Decoding JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Why do I get

> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

from this code:

```
import urllib.request,json 

n = urllib.request.urlopen("http://graph.facebook.com/55")
d = json.loads(str(n.readall()))
```

The full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#41>", line 1, in <module>
    d= json.loads(str(n.readall()))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\__init__.py", line 309, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\decoder.py", line 352, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\decoder.py", line 370, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

The output of `str(n.readall())`:

```
'b\'{"id":"55","name":"Jillian Copeland","first_name":"Jillian","last_name":"Copeland","username":"JCoMD","gender":"female","locale":"en_US"}\''
```

Maybe the `b` is throwing it off?

If that is the issue, how do I convert the binary stream from the `readall` to a string and not have that `b`?

I am trying to learn a little python so please keep that in mind.

I am using Python 3.3 in Windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use "byte-like object" from urlopen.read with json?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846112/use-byte-like-object-from-urlopen-read-with-json)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that this is an exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846112/use-byte-like-object-from-urlopen-read-with-json), but sadly there's no accepted answer.

On my end, this works:

```
import urllib.request,json 

n = urllib.request.urlopen("http://graph.facebook.com/55")
d= json.loads(n.readall().decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: If I don't decode, I get this: `TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`. I am using python 3.1 instead of 3.3, so that may be why though.

Comment: What I am missing here though, is how we determine that the response is UTF-8, and not in some other encoding. I didn't look into how to pull that from the urllib request.

Comment: The `content-type` header tells you that.